# How to leave some input elements and submit buttons unstyled in uniform(jquery)??

Tags: jquery, forms, uniform

Uniform is a form styling plugin.
I am using this on my new website. This is really good and working perfect but I have a site search where I want to put my own css style. 
How do I leave those fields unstyled by uniform so they can be styled by css. ???

Please help../

---

Solved it by something like

```
    $(function(){
    $("input, input:file, select, checkbox").uniform();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question and found an updated answer.

From https://github.com/pixelmatrix/uniform

> If you want to “un-uniform” something, simply call this function. It
>   will remove the inline styles, extra dom elements, and event handlers,
>   effectively restoring the element to it’s previous state.

```
$.uniform.restore([elem/selector string]);

// e.g.
$.uniform.restore("#something");
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to page

```
<style>
input, select, button { // name the appropriate selectors
    border: auto;
    background: auto;
    color: auto;
    position: auto;
}
</style>
```

or

dynamically remove css from page

```
<link id="uniformCss" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/uniform.default.css" /> 
<script>
$('#uniformCss').delete();
</script>
```

Comment: I want to leave just one text element and one submit button. All other buttons should remain styled with uniform.

Comment: you should check 1st solution, for this element e.g `div.selector select` {background:auto;color:auto;position:auto;}